# Comparing two array of object to return values that are not found

Tags: javascript, filter

I have two array of objects and I want to compare them and return values not found in the other

```
     arr1 = [{ text: "Company", value: 1},{ text: "Project", value: 3},{ 
         text: "Housing" value: 4}]
     arr2 = [{ newCol: "SumAmount", existCol: "Amount"}, { newCol: 
        "SumProj", existCol: "Proj"}]
```

I am comparing newCol values in arr2 against text in arr1, so since `SumAmount` and `SumProj` are not in the text values of arr1 I should get `SumAmount` and `SumProj`

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` and `some`

```js
arr1 = [{ text: "Company", value: 1},{ text: "Project", value: 3},{ text: "Housing" ,value: 4}]
arr2 = [{ newCol: "SumAmount", existCol: "Amount"}, { newCol: "SumProj", existCol: "Proj"}]
var res=arr2.filter(o=>!arr1.some(y=>y.text==o.newCol))
console.log(res)
```